# How to edit a post dynamically in wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress, post, plugins

I have created a small wordpress plugin that displays a list of people in a page via shortcode.

When the user clicks on one of the names from the list, a query_var gets set and my plugin catches the $_GET with the specific id of the person the user just clicked. All very well until now.

My problem is that now I want to display a page with the details (for the clicked element) but I dont seem to be able to edit the content or post that gets to the page and it returns me to the page with the list of people.

My question is how do I edit the post? I have tried adding a add_filter('the_content','my_func') to this, but this does not work since this hook is probably already passed.

I can access the post directly via get_content() or get_post(), but I dont seem to be able to make the page populated new data.

In other words... this does nore seem to work

```
$fid = $_GET['fid'];
global $wpdb;
$sql = "select * from fighters where fighter_id = {$fid} limit 1";
$fighter = $wpdb->get_row($sql);

$html = $this->_getFighterPageLayout($fighter);

$post = get_post();
$post->post_content = $html;
$post->title = 'test';
$post->private = false;
// or even just global $content = $html;
```

What am I doing wrong and what ways do I have to edit/update the content/post?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use the hooks of Wordpress to update the content. This works with the [add_filter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter) function

Try something like this, it should works

```
function mytheme_content_filter( $content ) {
     // Do stuff to $content, which contains the_content()
     // Then return it
     return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'mytheme_content_filter' );
```

Comment: So you are saying there is no other way?... I suppose thats what I was afraid because the plugin is already running so I'll have to hook it again and check the $_get at the function then.
thanks!